# Error while using gulp-spsync with SharePoint Framework

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, nodejs

Reference article that I followed to upload files to SharePoint Library:
[Automate publishing of your SharePoint Framework scripts to Office 365 public CDN](https://www.eliostruyf.com/automate-publishing-of-your-sharepoint-framework-scripts-to-office-365-public-cdn/).
 I updated *write-manifests.json* with correct cdnBasePath value and below is the gulpfile code looks like

'use strict';

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web');
const spSync = require('gulp-spsync');

build.task('upload-to-sharepoint', {
    execute: (config) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const deployFolder = require('./config/copy-assets.json');
            const folderLocation = `./${deployFolder.deployCdnPath}/**/*.js`;
            return gulp.src(folderLocation)
                .pipe(spSync({
                    "client_id": paramter.clientId,
                    "client_secret": paramter.clientSecret,
                    "site": `https://${paramter.tenant}.sharepoint.com/`,
                    "libraryPath": paramter.cdnLib,                                        
                    "publish": true
                }))
                .on('finish', resolve);
        });
    }
});
build.initialize(gulp);
```

When I run gulp task `gulp upload-to-sharepoint --ship` I am getting error:

> Uploading sample_en-us_6148166309dc16f1da067900ef6b71b1.js
>   Unhandled rejection Error in plugin 'gulp-spsync' Message:
>       Request error
>
> About to exit with code: 0 Process terminated before summary could be
>   written, possible error in async code not continuing! Trying to exit
>   with exit code 1

I can successfully run other gulp task like gulp bundle, gulp serve

Answer (score 1):

When using this gulp task, is it actually uploading files? If yes, can you do a quick change in one of the source files to check if it can fix it?

In the **node_modules** folder, look for a folder named **gulp-spsync** and open the **index.js** file. In that file there should be three lines like this: `cb(null,file)`. Change these to: `cb()`. Save the file, and run the gulp command again.

**Be aware**: this is not a solution to solve is as the gulp-spsync need to be fixed, but when it works, this can be changed in the code so that a new version of the plugin can be created.